# Unable to perform mathematical operations on Java List

Tags: java, arrays, generics, arraylist, java-stream

I am new to Java and need some clarification on handling `List` / `ArrayList` based on values that are added to the list from user inputs.

User inputs are obtained from a `UserInput` class with a `getUserInput()` method. This method takes in an integer `number_inputs` and returns a list of user inputs with length of `number_inputs`. The input type could vary (A user could input Integer or Double) hence it is generically typed `T`.

`UserInput` class looks like this:

```
public class UserInput<T> {
    private List<T> inputs = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public UserInput(List<T> inputs) {
        this.inputs = inputs;
    }
    
    public List<T> getUserInput(Integer number_inputs) {
            for(int i=1; i < number_inputs+1; i++) {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter number " + i);
                T userInput = (T) input.next();
                this.inputs.add(userInput);
            }
            return this.inputs;
    }
    
}
```

`getUserInputs()` is then called in the main class `CalculateValues`. Given the list of user inputs returned, I want to perform mathematical operations on the values (Eg. sum, division, etc). However the code below is not working with the error:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.String and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

```
public class CalculateValues {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> vals = new ArrayList<>();
        UserInput<Integer> userInput = new UserInput<>(vals);
        List<Integer> inputValues = userInput.getUserInput(2);
        System.out.println(inputValues.get(0) + inputValues.get(1)); // Error occurs here
    }

}
```

Is there a way to do this without making use of array streams? I am mainly confused why the error is showing since my list values in `inputValues` are already typed as Integers, so why is the compiler detecting my list values as Strings?

Comment: I wouldn't do `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` instead each loop iteration, it's wasteful, do it before the start of the loop instead. I would consider `T userInput = (T) input.next();` a bad idea, `next` is returning a `String` trying to cast it to something like an `Integer` is going to fail and this is actually where you error occurred. I would suggest you need some kind of "convert" which new how to take a `String` and convert it to the expected value you actually want

Comment: Yes, as @MadProgrammer pointed out, the error is actually at `T userInput = (T) input.next();`, where you're taking a value of type `String`, and casting it to `T`, which happens to be `Integer` in this case.  If you're dealing with integer values, you'll need to call `nextInt()` instead of `next()`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem @MadProgrammer Thanks for the input. To build on the problem, if I explicitly use ```nextInt()```, I will definitely get a runtime error if I input a ```Character``` or ```String```. Is there a way to allow such input types then? Or will the best workaround be to create a fresh class with a ```Scanner``` to handle ```Character```/```String``` input types. Just thinking out loud if I would want to handle an array of such types in the future.

Comment: Honestly, I'd be inclined to just work with a `List<Double>` and assume everything is `Double`.  I'm assuming you're not concerned about the problems with floating point arithmetic - if you are, then you could consider `List<BigDecimal>`, although `BigDecimal` has problems of its own.  As far as dealing with input that can't be interpreted as a `double`, you'll have to write some code to dealing with that.  The appropriate place to do that is in a `catch` block, when you catch a `NumberFormatException`.  If you're new to Java, you might want to read up on `try` and `catch`.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd recommend is to reduce the scope of generic-type `T`, and simply use a `Number` object.  This will cover both `Double` and `Integer`.

You'll need to check the value from the `input`.
Rather than using `input.next`, use `input.nextLine`.

If the value contains a decimal point, add it to `inputs` as a `Double`, otherwise add it as an `Integer`.

```java
public class UserInput {
    private List<Number> inputs;

    public UserInput(List<Number> inputs) {
        this.inputs = inputs;
    }

    public List<Number> getUserInput(Integer number_inputs) {
        String string;
        for(int i=1; i < number_inputs+1; i++) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter number " + i);
            string = input.nextLine();
            if (string.contains(".")) {
                this.inputs.add(Double.parseDouble(string));
            } else {
                this.inputs.add(Integer.parseInt(string));
            }
        }
        return this.inputs;
    }

}
```

Then, in your `CalculateValues` class, you'll need to differentiate the results, and add accordingly.

```java
public class CalculateValues {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Number> vals = new ArrayList<>();
        UserInput userInput = new UserInput(vals);
        List<Number> inputValues = userInput.getUserInput(2);
        Number numberA = inputValues.get(0);
        Number numberB = inputValues.get(1);
        if (numberA instanceof Integer && numberB instanceof Integer)
            System.out.println(numberA.intValue() + numberB.intValue());
        else if (numberA instanceof Integer && numberB instanceof Double)
            System.out.println(numberA.intValue() + numberB.doubleValue());
        else if (numberA instanceof Double && numberB instanceof Integer)
            System.out.println(numberA.doubleValue() + numberB.intValue());
        else if (numberA instanceof Double && numberB instanceof Double) {
            System.out.println(numberA.doubleValue() + numberB.doubleValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, you can just store all the values as `Double`. It has more than enough space to accommodate an `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
T userInput = (T)input.next();
```

`input.next()` returns a `String`. Always.

To fix this, specify the Scanner method the instance should use:

```
public class UserInput<T> {
    private Function<Scanner, T> reader;
    
    public UserInput(Function<Scanner, T> reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }
    
    public List<T> getUserInput(Integer number_inputs) {
        List<T> inputs = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i=1; i < number_inputs+1; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter number " + i);
            T userInput = reader.apply(input);
            inputs.add(userInput);
        }
        return inputs;
    }
}
```

And use it, for example for Double input:

```
UserInput<Double> ui = new UserInput<>(Scanner::nextDouble);
    List<Double> doubles = ui.getUserInput(2);
```

If there's a Scanner method for the type, just specify it using a method reference as done here.

If there isn't a method, create your own using a lambda:

```
UserInput<MyType> ui = new UserInput<>(scanner -> /* some code that returns a MyType using scanner */);
```

Note the following other improvements:

- deletion of the unnecessary `inputs` field, especially the unnecessary re-initialisation via constructor
- Moving initialisation of the Scanner to *before* the loop, so you're not creating a new Scanner every iteration

Comment: The `Scanner` should be closed, as well.

Comment: How would you handle the calculation process?  That part stumped me, since an `instanceof` check is required for a `Number` object.  Is there a closure for this?

Comment: @Reilas That is already taken care of with this code. OP's code did an unsafe cast from String to T, so a Strings get added to the List but the code believes them to be Integers. That is discovered when the elements are accessed, at which point there is a class cast exception trying to cast String as Integer. Remember that at runtime there is no type safety - everything is Object. There is only compile time type safety and hard casting like OP did bypasses that safety. With my code there is no cast, so it's type safe. Scanner doesn't *need* to be closed - that happens when garbage collected

Comment: Of course it should be closed.  Why else would it implement `Closeable`?  I know what you mean, though.  It's poor practice though, since that is not always the case with other `Closeable` objects.

Comment: Above solution works for `Integer` and `Double` inputs. How about `String` inputs? If I try to initialize an instance of `String` type, I am getting an error here:

`UserInput<String> userStringInput = new UserInput<String>(Scanner::nextLine);`
`<String> inputStrings = userInput.getUserInput(2); // Error occurs here`

And the error message is `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Double> to List<String>`

Comment: @Reilas - NO, this code should NOT close the Scanner.  Firstly, you should never try to close System.in.  Secondly, if you're writing a method that works with a Scanner, it's almost certainly not that method's responsibility to close the Scanner - if closing the Scanner is appropriate, then that belongs in some other piece of code.  And thirdly, as Bohemian pointed out, the garbage collector will look after closing any Scanner that it comes across, so there's no point in adding extra cruft.

Comment: @Ry123 I assume you meant `List<String> inputStrings = userInput.getUserInput(2);` and not `<String> inputStrings = userInput.getUserInput(2);`, but I have a hard time understanding how that could not work. Please create a [mcve] on an online playground (eg http://ideone.com or https://onecompiler.com/java, etc) and share the link here.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, then why in the JavaDoc for `Scanner` does it provide examples that all use `close`?

Comment: @Reilas The doc says, and the source code confirms, that `close()` closes the input if it is Closeable. All examples in the doc have `String` input. Since String is not Closeable, calling `close()` does nothing useful, so the examples should not have that - it's nonsense. In the context of this question, the input is `System.in`, an `InputStream` which is Closeable. Calling `close()` here will close STDIN, which in some OS will nuke your terminal. The only reason to call `close()` is for input you want to close like a `FileInputStream` *and* where it's not being closed elsewhere.

Comment: @Bohemian, it's the official documentation, so it's obviously not non-sense.  The competence you're having is that you're implying the `close` method only closes the stream.  It's doesn't, take a look at the [openJDK - Scanner.java#close](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java#L1176).  It is setting both `sourceClosed` and `closed` to `true`, and is setting `source` to `null`.  While I understand you and the other poster's inference, it's just not logical to provide an empirical solution on a technical basis.

Comment: @Reilas the doc is nonsense, as I have shown. And those other fields being set is done only so further reading from the input throws an exception; nothing actually useful occurs when calling close() on a Scanner whose input in a String.

Comment: @Bohemian, I guess you're right.  It isn't called a procedure for nothing, though, remember.

Comment: @Reilas Examples in a Javadoc don't necessarily reflect best practice.  As I explained before, (and as Bohemian explained better), you should NEVER try to close `System.in`.  If a method does a good amount of processing on a `Scanner`, then closing the `Scanner` should be a separate operation, in a separate method, so that it can be called _only_ if it's appropriate to do so.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, yet, the documentation, written by the implementers of the language, show by example, doing so.  In addition to the fact that they developed the code in a manor that allows you to access a method used for closing the object.  I'm sure they had a meeting and said, "alright, let's add a method here that is completely useless.  We'll throw some random code in there."

Comment: @Reilas It's not useless, just useless *here*. The useful usecase for calling `close()` would be when the Scanner is created over a resource that should be closed asap ( eg FileInputStream) and handed to code that uses the Scanner and it was decided that this code is responsible for closing the input stream after it's finished reading bytes. Such code has no access to the Closeable resource, so the only way to close it is to call Scanner's close(). Scanner effectively wraps the InputStream and delgates closing to the input stream it wraps.

Answer (score 0):

When I compile the given code, the compiler gives me an "unchecked cast" warning:

```
UserInput.java:18: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
            T userInput = (T) input.next();
                                        ^
  required: T
  found:    String
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class UserInput
1 warning
```

The reason for this is that Java generics are implemented via a process known as [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure), whereby the specific generic type is known at compile time, but unknown at runtime.  What this means in Java is that much of generic type safety is only verified at compile time, but not checked again at runtime.

In this specific case, the runtime type of `T` is `Object`.  The "unchecked cast" warning is telling you that the Java runtime won't actually be doing any actual casting checks.  This is true even despite the fact that in this case the `vals` variable is declared as `List<Integer>`.

The `input.next()` call returns a `String`, since that's what [`Scanner.next`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) returns.  However, since type parameters are implemented via erasure, and you have incorrectly assured the compiler that `userInput` was a variable of type `T` (`Integer` in your case), the `userInput` value is a `String`, not a `T`.  Then, you add this to the `inputs` `ArrayList<T>`, which now contains a `String` value despite `T` being an `Integer`.  Finally, the error you're seeing: `inputValues.get(0)` is implemented under the covers as `(Integer) inputValues.get(0)`.  And since this value is actually a `String`, you get the `ClassCastException`, since a `String` cannot be cast to an `Integer`.

This, then is why the compiler warning is there: to warn you that you're doing something that could potentially break the Java type system.  Generics are implemented in a way such that, if you do not have any compiler warnings about unsafe operations, you should be guaranteed to have correctly typed code that doesn't produce these sorts of errors.  Once you ignore the warnings, you lose that safety, and this sort of situation can be the result.